# Determining subspaces in P3

Tags: linear-algebra

Alright, so I am aware that {p ∈ P3 : p'(1)=0} is a subspace of P3

However, what about if p'(0)=1 ?

is {p ∈ P3 : p'(0)=1} a subspace of P3?

My gut tells be "no", but an actual explanation would help understanding.

Comment: Hint: how do you check that {p ∈ P3 : p'(1)=0}? Does the same criteria work for {p ∈ P3 : p'(0)=1}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subspace must always contain the zero vector.

$$
0 \notin \{ p \in P_3 : p'(0) = 1 \}
$$

So $\{ p \in P_3 : p'(0) = 1 \}$ is not a subspace.